# How to find the number of perfect array?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

We got two integers x and y, and we call an array is a perfect array if and only if it satisfies the following conditions:

1. The elements in the array are integers.
2. The length of the array is exactly y.
3. The product of all elements is exactly x.

So how to find the number of beautiful arrays for different x and y?

For example, if x is 3 and y is 2, there are four beautiful arrays:

```
[1,3],[3,1],[-1,-3],[-3,-1]
```

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share your findings. Have you already some code?

Comment: Try the layout features of the online editor and use the preview for pretty results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do few examples first:

1. `x = 30, y = 3`, `x`'s prime factors are `2, 3, 5`. Possible combinations are `2 * 3 * 5`, `6 * 5`, `2 * 15`, `3 * 10`, `30`. For every possible combination of length `L` we need to count the number of possible arrangement of its elements in 3 slots, that is `y!/(y-L)!`. We obtain `6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 3 = 27`.
2. `x = 36, y = 5`, `x`'s prime factors are `2, 2, 3, 3`. Writing in the same way as the previous example would be tedious, so let's think about `y` bins in which we want to put `2, 2` and `3, 3`. The number of ways we can distribute `2, 2` into 5 bins can be computed with the help of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), we need to put 4 bars among `2, 2`. There is `6!/(4!2!) = 15`. The same for `3, 3`. So, the answer is `225`.

---

1. Factor x into prime divisors. Such factorization is [unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). And takes up to `sqrt(x)`.

   [image]
2. Count the number of ways we can distribute every p<sub>i</sub> into `y` bins. Multiply.

   [image]
3. Account for positive/negative multiplying by

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to factor x. This can be done in O(√x) (googl it).
Let x=Πp_i^k_i (p_i is a prime number)
Count the number of distributing ∑k_i for y cells.
This is (∑k_i+x-1)!/(x-1)!/∑k_i
There is also the degree of freedom for positive and negative.
This is the number of way to make pairs.